# Abit stuck why i cant get this working :/

Tags: java

```
public class Robot
{
    public static void main(String []args){

        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        String path = "";
        int N = 2;
        int ol1_right = 1; 
        int ol1_down = 1;
        int ol2_right = 1; 
        int ol2_down = 1;
        buildPath (right, down, path, allPaths, N);
        System.out.println (allPath(grid));

    }

    public void BuildPath (int right, int down, String path, 
        ArrayList<String> allPaths, int N){
            path += "(" + down "," + right + ")->";
            if (right == N-1 && down == N-1){
                allPaths.add(path);
                return;
            }
            else if (right +1 == ol1_right && down == ol1_down) && (right +1 == 
            ol2_right && down == ol2_down);{
            return;
            }
            if (right +1 == ol1_right && down == N-1) || (right +1 == ol2_right
            && down == N-1);{
            return;
            }
            if (right == N-1 && down +1 == ol1_down) || (right == N-1 && down +1
            == ol2_right);{
            return;
            }
            if (right == N-1 || right +1 == ol1_right && down == N-1 || 
            right +1 == ol2_right && down == N-1){
                BuildPath (right, down + 1, path, allPaths, N);
            }
            else if (down == N-1 || right +1 == ol1_right && down == ol1_down && right +1 == 
            ol2_right && down == ol2_down ){
                BuildPath (right + 1, down, path, allPaths, N);
            }
            else 
            BuildPath (right + 1, down, path, allPaths, N);
            BuildPath (right, down + 1, path, allPaths, N);
    }
}
```

Sorry im still new to this sort of thing and im stuck on trying to get this program to work but sort of stuck on where to go to next. I get errors such as "illegal start of expression" ( thrown when using || and &&) or "not a statement" (path += "(" + down "," + right + ")->";) All im trying to do is get the (robot) to move along the grid while only moving down and right but also have the ability to mark certain parts of the gird as off limits. any help would be much appreciated, i know it all looks terrible but just trying to get the hang of this so sorry for any rookie errors or dumb mistakes still very new :)

Comment: because that isn't javascript for a start

Comment: sorry swear I hit java

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow, Daniel. You should include in your question which line throws the compilation error or the exception, maybe the complete stacktrace for it, and tell us what you're trying to achieve. Also, if I were you, I would read about jUnit and how to unit test your code. That would greatly help you figuring out where the problem is, and lead to cleaner code as a side effect.

Comment: I fixed the tag for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I see (and from the errors my IDE gave to this code),
you have some basic compilation issues.

In the method **main(String[])**, referring to this line:

```
buildPath (right, down, path, allPaths, N);
```

You have not defined the vars "right", "down", "allPaths" in main. These are the internal names of the arguments in **BuildPath(int, int, String,   ArrayList, int)** and you cannot use their names from outside.

The same goes for what is happening in **BuildPath(int, int, String,   ArrayList, int)**, you cannot use "ol1_right", "ol1_down" as they are defined only in **main(String[])**.

Another separate issue is in this line:

```
path += "(" + down "," + right + ")->";
```

Add a **+** after **down**.

Yet another issue is with semi-colons in if statements:

```
else if (right +1 == ol1_right && down == ol1_down) && (right +1 == 
    ol2_right && down == ol2_down);{
```

Should be (remove **;** and add outer **(** **)**):

```
else if ((right +1 == ol1_right && down == ol1_down) && (right +1 == 
    ol2_right && down == ol2_down)) {
```

Comment: Thanks you! very helpful :) much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

There's a number of problems, for starters in `Main()` you have

```
int ol1_right = 1; 
int ol1_down = 1;
int ol2_right = 1; 
int ol2_down = 1;
```

which you declare and initialize but then try to access from `BuildPath()` without passing them as parameters. You can't do that, because in Java the scope of a variable is limited to the block it is defined in unless you specify otherwise.

In your case you would probably need to move those four variables to `BuildPath()` itself. Then again, you don't seem to ever change them, so I would make one single constant out of all of them.

Also, `list` doesn't seem like it is used, so it's probably redundant.

Not a Java guy, and I don't have a compiler handy to tell you exactly what's wrong. Try making a new file and adding code back a little at a time and see what the compiler complains about.

If I may, it looks to me like you're getting ahead of yourself if you're doing recursion without really knowing Java's syntax. I would concentrate on learning at least the basics of that first.